# how to use XPath query to get text under certain element but not in any element?

Tags: xpath, html-parsing

Not sure if this title make sense. 
The piece of HTML is like this:

```
<div id="A">
  <span class="B"> XXXX </span>
  MMM
  <span class="B"> ZZZZ </span>
  NNN
  <div class="C">
    <span class="B">
      OOO
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to use XPath query pattern to get the text "MMM" and "NNN" ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the text for a node with a particular id, then use the following expression:

```
//div[@id='A']/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can just use `/div/text()` to get any text nodes under the initial div root. You'd only get all text nodes if you did `//text()`